# CAS vs Okta Vs Keycloak comparisions as an SSO solution

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, cas, okta, cons

Which is the best option for SSO implementation Keycloack Vs CAS Vs Okta? I'm specifically looking for the disadvantages of each service to identify the best suitability for my system.

Comment: https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/13120-identity-management-and-single-sign-on-how-much-flexibility might help you a bit but prob won't answer all your questions - slides at https://www.slideshare.net/RyanDawson16/identity-management-and-single-sign-on-how-much-flexibility-5

Comment: There is a lot to consider in this space. It could help if you could narrow your question by specifying particular features that you need coverage for or are concerned you might hit problems with or if you could break it into multiple questions. Or are you looking for a feature comparison chart?

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a solution which provides SSO to different web applications (different products in our system using their own username and password based authentication). Also, the solution should be the right fit for API-API communication and Social sign on as well. Should support Oatuh2, OpenID, SAML and multi factor authntication.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Both Keycloak and Okta should provide what you're looking for. I'm not sure about CAS as I haven't used it in 10 years. Since both Keycloak and Okta use OAuth 2.0/OIDC, you might even be able to use Keycloak in development, and Okta in production.

I've implemented OAuth 2.0 / OIDC support in [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech). It uses Keycloak (in a Docker container) by default, and [provides instructions for switching to Okta](https://www.jhipster.tech/security/#oauth2). Thanks to the power of Spring Security and Spring Boot, you only need to override some properties to switch between the two!

Comment: So Okta provides the same features as Keycloak and the only difference is that Okta is a paid enterprise solution and Keyclock is a open-source solution?

Comment: Yes. But you can also [sign up for an Okta developer account](https://developer.okta.com/signup) and get 1000 MAU (monthly active users) for free! You can also run Keycloak in a Docker container and use it offline. You can't do that with Okta.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "use Keycloak in development", does Keycloak have any disadvantage?

Comment: @liuyong I work in a multi-billion dollar company and we use Keycloak in all environments including production. We have been doing that for the last 7 years without any issues.